# How to upload files to a server: Multiple Files and Custom UI

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a UI that would let the end user upload multiple file sot a server, on a custom UI - pretty much the same way GMail or Outlook.net is doing it.

Few things to node:

1. The `<input type="file">` is ugly - and not standard (IE shows a button named 'Browse' to the left of the file name. Chrome shows a button named 'Choose' to the right of the file name).
2. Most suggestions how to do the UI suggests hiding a input file element with `opacity=0`, but on top of by custom UI. The 'click' event will open the dialog box, and upon return the file name (without the path) will be available as a $('#file').val(). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8974633/341971) question, as well as the sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4BS7/1/).
3. I'm also aware HTML5 has a `multiple="multiple"` attribute now, which will let the user select multiple files.
4. However, I'm looking for a multiple file solution, which will work on IE8 and above (as well as WebKit, Mozila).
5. Some people suggested Google is using Flash. This is not true. Their multi file upload is working when flash is disabled.

Now, here is my biggest surprise: Using the developer tools (F12) on both IE and Chrome, looking at both GMail and Outlook.NET - **both implementations do not have a `<input type='file'>` element in the tree** (as far as I can tell). Moreover, both implementations are working with IE8 (flash disabled).

What is going on? How do they do it?

**EDIT**: Why do I think they don't use file input element? Open the developer tools (F12), switch to Console, type: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`. There are 24 input elements, 19 of which are type=hidden, none is type=file.

**EDIT 2:**Thank you all responders and commentators. Indeed - the "there is no other way" argument (in comment) below was valid. As it turns out, both Outlook.NET and GMail will have a `<input type='file'>` element, which they will add dynamically, only when the user clicks the 'Attach a file' button. Then, they will send a 'click' event to the element, which will trigger the select file dialog.

The witness this, use the F12 development tool (either in Chrome, or in IE), and in the interactive console type: document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]'). Note that in both implementations, the element is a direct child of body (with display=none).

They do **not** use iframe for the upload (unlike the only answer below), but simple XHR code to upload, which is now, in HTML5 is available.

The best resource on the Web for how to do it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications. I've went through the steps of @Jay below (which are great), but the Mozilla page is simpler, **which is my recommendation**. Also, take a quick look at the jsfiddle sample on @Niranjan comment.

Comment: use a label[for=id] and hide the input display:none; since labels style way more consistently than inputs...

Comment: First off, google IS using flash, but only when the File API is not supported.  Second, of course they are using a file input element.  There is no other way to present a file chooser to the user without resorting to flash or java.

Comment: @Ray, please find my edit. I totally understand the argument "There is no other way", so I'm puzzled why can't I find it (I was also looking at two unrelated iframes).

Comment: @Uri The `<input type='file'>` are created at runtime and `click` event is invoked on them. And all that happens when you click the So called `Attach Files` div. Have look at this.  http://jsfiddle.net/A4BS7/31/ and also you can consider Drag and Drop feature as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220330/multiple-file-upload-using-html5-drag-and-drop-fails-as-multiple-files-get-same

Comment: No, its usually because the input elements are created in an Iframe allowing it to post without refreshing the page, thus a `document.getElementsByTagName` won't return input[type=file] because its in a different frame.

Comment: @Jay Had it been created in an `iframe` then that would have been found during the `Inspect Element`, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently implemented a multi file upload UI for an old asp.net website, but the concepts should be the same.

I'm not very good at writing (summarizing code) but here goes.

1. Create a number of IFrames. I had problems trying to write IFrames after the document loaded due to security restrictions, so had the server render as many as I though the user would use at once.
2. Add an 'upload' button and handler which first adds a `load` handler to one of the iframes.

   var frame = $('iframe:first');

**in the frame load handler ---**

```
frame.load(function () { /* all the code below* /});
```

2.a. Write the input tag for file and what ever other elements you like into the frame like this

```
frame.contents().find('body').html("html goes here");
```

2.b. Now add a handler to the file input in your frame and submit that form:

```
frame.contents().find('#fileUpload').change( /*submit the form */)
```

2.c. Now invoke the file upload dialog

```
frame.contents().find('#fileUpload').click();
```

2.d. Now that line will block until the dialog returns. When it does you have to check the value of the file upload control for `null` in case they canceled. This is where i marked the iframe as not in use.

2.e. Ether way you'll need to unbind from the load of the iframe and rebind to a different method that will handle the return (upload complete)

```
frame.unbind('load');
frame.load(function () { /* handle file uploaded */})
```

2.e.1. This is where I reported success to the user and released the frame so it could be reused.

2.e.2. Finally unbind from load again from the upload complete method

All of that is in your **frame load handler**

3.Now cause the frame to load

```
frame.load();
```

At least thats how I did it. I uploaded all the files to a handler which reported file % and a loop inside the parent page fired off ajax getting and displaying the progress of each file.

The main idea is if you want multi file upload in an 'ajaxy' style but not using flash or Html 5 you'll need to use a collection of iframes and some fancy script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Jay. +25 for being the only answer :-), but also accurate. See my EDIT2 for a little bit simpler solution.

Comment: Aye you can upload files without an IFrame as long as the browser supports HTML5. At the time of my writing the above code HTML5 and other plugins were not an option. Not the most elegant solution, but it sure was fun writing it. Cheers.